# Como centrar este div usando las clases de bootstrap 4 (sin CSS puro)

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

me gustaria centrar el `div` con **id** `carta` sin usar `CSS`
 como podria hacerlo ?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 align-center">

  <div id="carta" class="card pt-1 border border-secondary" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Nombre tienda</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Tienda online</h6>
      <a routerLink="/login" class="card-link btn btn-info">Iniciar Sesion</a>
      <a routerLink="/registro" class="card-link btn btn-success">Registrarse</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "sin CSS"? ¿Sin usar CSS propio? ¿Sólo usando las clases proporcionadas por Bootstrap?

Comment: Si, eso es. Sin hacer un `margin: 0 auto;` en **CSS**

Comment: ¿Qué es "CSS puro"? ¿Existe un "CSS impuro"? ¿Cuál es la diferencia con sólo "CSS"?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo a tu div, la clase

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="center-block">hola
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo he probado antes, ejecutandolo aqui y no lo ajusta en el centro.

Comment: Ya probaste colocando en el div que contiene los elementos, la clase mx-auto?

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que añadir `.row` `.justify-content-center` al div que contiene todo, de la siguiente forma:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 row justify-content-center">

        <div id="carta" class="card  pt-1 border border-secondary" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Nombre tienda</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Tienda online</h6>
                <a routerLink="/login" class="card-link btn btn-info">Iniciar Sesion</a>
                <a routerLink="/registro" class="card-link btn btn-success">Registrarse</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: lo he probado, pero no me funciona

Comment: Yo lo he probado también y me funciona perfectamente, pero bueno, otra alternativa que puedes usar es ponerle la clase `mx-auto` junto a la clase `card`

Comment: ya lo puse, es que tenia algo por ahi raro. Muchas gracias. Como podria centrarlo tambien verticalmente ?

Comment: Pues buscando un poco no es difícil encontrar soluciones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4
A veces pecamos un poco de vagos. No te lo tomes a mal @josanangel. Pero antes de preguntar hay que hacer los deberes.

Comment: Hola @DanielAbril aunque es cierto que esta pregunta se ha hecho muchas veces, tratemos primero de buscar el contenido de SO en español que cada vez es más completo.

Comment: Huy perdón, me paso tantas horas al día en bilingüe que ni me di cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar flexbox y la propiedad justify-content, como sabrás bootstrap trabaja con un sistema de grillas, pues justify-content te permite alinear horizontalmente y verticalmente te dejo la referencia: [Documentacion flex bootstrap 4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)
En tu codigo debes agregar **d-flex justify-content-center** primer div.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div id="carta" class="card pt-1 border border-secondary" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Nombre tienda</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Tienda online</h6>
          <a routerLink="/login" class="card-link btn btn-info">Iniciar Sesion</a>
          <a routerLink="/registro" class="card-link btn btn-success">Registrarse</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```